# Binding Razor View fields to a Model in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having trouble submitting the fields in my View (Textboxes and Checkboxes) to my Model and am not sure how to continue. Every time i hit the button that is supposed to submit to the model, the controller checks the fields that should have been set by the view, but keeps returning false. So either they haven't been set in the first place, or the controller is reading them wrong. Either way, I am at a loss. Please help :X

View (somewhat simplified):

```
@model Model

@Html.ValidationSummary()

@{ Html.BeginForm("PrintReport", "Controller", FormMethod.Get, new {     @class = "form_ll" }); }

<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>

<div class="group">
    @Html.ValidTextBoxFor(Model => Model.ToDate) 
    @Html.ValidTextBoxFor(Model => Model.FromDate)

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Geplakt)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Geparafeerd)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Verschreven)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Geannuleerd)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Vermist)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Vernietigd)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Onbruikbaar)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Misdruk)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Teruggevonden)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.InOnderzoek)
</div>
<div class="button">
    @Html.Button("Print")
</div>
@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

Model:

```
[Serializable]
public class Model : DomainObject
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }

    public bool Geplakt { get; set; }
    public bool Geparafeerd { get; set; }
    public bool Verschreven { get; set; }
    public bool Geannuleerd  { get; set; }
    public bool Vermist  { get; set; }
    public bool Vernietigd { get; set; }
    public bool Onbruikbaar { get; set; }
    public bool Misdruk { get; set; }
    public bool Teruggevonden { get; set; }
    public bool InOnderzoek { get; set; }

    public Model()
    {
        // Constructor
    }               
}
```

Controller:

```
public class Controller : ModelController<Model>
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Model = new Model();
        return InternalIndex();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult InternalIndex()
    {
        return View("Index", Model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PrintReport()
    {
        if (!Model.FromDate.HasValue || !Model.ToDate.HasValue)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "At leaste one date is null");
        else {
            if (Model.FromDate.Value.CompareTo(Model.ToDate.Value) >= 0)
                ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "First date is later then the second one");
        }
        if(Model.IsAnythingChecked())
            ModelState.AddModelError("Checkboxes", "You haven't checked any checkboxes");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("PrintReport", Model);
        }
        else
        {
            return InternalIndex();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using GET instead of POST. You're sending your model to the controller not receiving information. The one line should read this:

```
@{ Html.BeginForm("PrintReport", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new {     @class = "form_ll" }); }
```

You also need to send your Model to the controller and set the method in your controller to HttpPost:

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult PrintReport(Model m)
{
    if (!Model.FromDate.HasValue || !Model.ToDate.HasValue)
        ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "At leaste one date is null");
    else {
        if (Model.FromDate.Value.CompareTo(Model.ToDate.Value) >= 0)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "First date is later then the second one");
    }
    if(Model.IsAnythingChecked())
        ModelState.AddModelError("Checkboxes", "You haven't checked any checkboxes");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("PrintReport", Model);
    }
    else
    {
        return InternalIndex();
    }
}
```

Give that a try.

Comment: I got the same answer 5 times here, so obviously this was the problem. I assumed, because the PrintReport method was only accessible through the Index method - and the Index method constructs the Model, PrintReport was using the same Model variable. I guess it wasn't, because passing a Model in the Action worked. Although I find it kind of strange I didn't have to use the passed Model.

Comment: I've made the same mistake before. When the PrintReport is posted to it doesn't go through the Index controller method it will go directly to PrintReport method. Since you're posting with a form, all the information from the form has to be binded to your model as a parameter in the PrintReport controller so you can access all the properties.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're POSTing form data to a GET only controller. Also, you haven't told the controller to expect a model. Try this (note the removal of the [HTTPGet decorator]:

```
public ActionResult PrintReport(Model m)
{
    if (!m.FromDate.HasValue || !m.ToDate.HasValue)
        ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "At leaste one date is null");
    else {
        if (m.FromDate.Value.CompareTo(m.ToDate.Value) >= 0)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "First date is later then the second one");
    }
    if(m.IsAnythingChecked())
        ModelState.AddModelError("Checkboxes", "You haven't checked any checkboxes");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("PrintReport", Model);
    }
    else
    {
        return InternalIndex();
    }
}
```

I don't have a setup currently available to test, but that should work

Answer (score 3):

You need to have two overloads of your `PrintReport` action method.

- One with an `[HttpGet]` attribute. This is used to return your web page
- One with an `[HttpPost]` attribute, that takes an argument of type `Model` (your model class, which **really** should be updated to have a name that describes what it is a model of). This is used when your form submits values back to the web server.

Your form should be updated do a POST (change `FormMethod.Get` to `FormMethod.Post`).

MVC model binding should then sort the rest out for you, creating an instance of your model type for the second overload of your `PrintReport` action method.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass your model back as a parameter of your controller action to see the changes reflected in the view, i.e.

`public ActionResult PrintReport(Model model) {`

Answer (score 1):

What's the content of your `ModelController<Model>` class?  My suspicion is that you create a new model in that class, and that's what your code is referring to when you write `if (!Model.FromDate.HasValue` and similar.

However, there's no way for your controller to know which model your view is posting back about.  In order to change this, you need to do three things:

1. Add a parameter to your `PrintReport` method to represent the model you're processing, and use that instead of `Model` in your code.
2. Mark the `PrintReport` method with `[HttpPost]` so that the model can be passed to the method.
3. Change your form to use Post instead of Get.